# Como trabajan IF ,THE Y ELSE en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente linea de código pero me arroja error y no tengo claro porque , por lo que veo la sentecia esta bien , pero en else me dice "Declarion or statement expected".

```
if (aprobado = 1) then
{
 comentario = "Req. Aprobado: " & comentario
  }else{
    comentario = "Req. Rechazado: " & comentario
   end if
    };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es aprobado == 1.. son por lo menos dos ==. y no hay ni then, ni end if. Deberias revisar la sintaxis de como se escribe en js

Comment: el `then` no existe en JavaScript, solo es `IF/ELSE IF/ELSE` eso mas lo que aporta gbianchi

Answer (score 2):

En javaScript para un if no requiere **then** ni **end**, también debes tener en cuenta que para concatenar strings debes usar **+** y no **&**, otra cosa que veo en tu código es que en el if estas asignando (aprobado = 1) y no comparando el valor por lo que tampoco te funcionaria por ese lado.

el código funcionando correctamente seria asi:

```js
let comentario = ""

let aprobado = 1;
if (aprobado == 1) {
 comentario = "Req. Aprobado: " + comentario
}else{
    comentario = "Req. Rechazado: " + comentario
};

console.log(comentario)
```

Comment: Mil gracias eso era :)